# What is the syntax for selector parameters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm adding a `UIRefreshControl` to my `UITableViewController`, but I can't figure out the `addTarget:action:` syntax.

```
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:[what goes here?], forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

I tried searching the docs but didn't come up with a working example.

Comment: For example: `Selector("buttonTapped")`

Comment: Search again. Hint: it's just a String!

Comment: refreshCntrl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshCntrl.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
refreshCntrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Please Wait...")                                refreshCntrl.addTarget(self, action:"refreshControlValueChanged", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)                         tableView.addSubview(refreshCntrl)